# How to merge different value types in python list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

Let's say I've got three lists below:

```py
data = [
    {"type": "special", "prize": "32220402"},
    {"type": "grand", "prize": "99194290"},
    [
        {"type": "first", "prize": "16525386"},
        {"type": "first", "prize": "28467179"},
        {"type": "first", "prize": "27854976"},
    ],
    [
        {"type": "second", "prize": "6525386"},
        {"type": "second", "prize": "8467179"},
        {"type": "second", "prize": "7854976"},
    ],
]
```

How can I combine all the values in the list above to:

```py
[
    {"type": "special", "prize": "32220402"},
    {"type": "grand", "prize": "99194290"},
    {"type": "first", "prize": "16525386"},
    {"type": "first", "prize": "28467179"},
    {"type": "first", "prize": "27854976"},
    {"type": "second", "prize": "6525386"},
    {"type": "second", "prize": "8467179"},
    {"type": "second", "prize": "7854976"},
]
```

What is the syntactically cleanest way to accomplish this?

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make a flat list out of a list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-do-i-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists)

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution:

```
[data[0], data[1], *data[2], *data[3]]
```

If you prefer a more general approach:

```
[dct for x in data for dct in (x if isinstance(x, list) else (x,))]
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is a large number, you can use looping as:

```
result = []
for i in data:
    if isinstance(i, list):
        for j in i:
            result.append(j)
    else:
        result.append(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to flatten embedded lists, and keep the rest as it is. This should do it:

```
flat = []
for e in data:
    if isinstance(e, list):
        flat.extend(e)
    else:
        flat.append(e)
```